# Setting data on ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a RecyclerView in my project and I am having an issue where my RecyclerView is being populated by the same values as if the values are being overwritten inside the `forEach` in `onBindViewHolder` below:

```
   class ProfListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>{
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    public ProfListAdapter(Context context) {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType){
        return new ViewHolder(mLayoutInflater
        .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, viewGroup, false));
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){
    System.out.println(position);
        final String profName;
        Integer k = 0;
        for (Integer key : mData.keySet()) {
            viewHolder.setData(mData.get(key));
        }


    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = ProfPager.newIntent(getActivity(), position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id._prof); // galleryimage
    }
    private void setData(String profName){
        mTextView.setText(profName);
        System.out.println("setData" + profName);
    }
}
```

When I log out to the console I can see that the value in `setData()` is getting the correct item to display. However, what is being displayed inside the fragment is just the last `profName` that is comes across in the `forEach`. What could be causing this behaviour? Here is a link to the entire `fragment`: https://pastebin.com/xS7CSbbK

If I use the `position`, it does not always coincide with the key in the `Hashmap` that stores the `SQLite` `_id`.

Comment: why you want that for each loop?

Comment: Why the for each ? in onBindViewHolder you are changing repeadly the data of the same viewHolder isntance and obviously at the end all will be set to the last value in the list. You have to set the value corresponding to the position. That's why onBindViewHolder  has position as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Setting data on ViewHolder

You may not need the for each loop inside the onBindViewHolder, instead try to set data using the position value available at onBindViewHolder. cheers :)

Comment: I guess I should've clarified that I need the position to coincide with the key from the database. So my fragment gets populated with the database entries, clicking on an entry in the list will open a new display fragment. Just using the position alone, if I click on the entry, it may display a different entry in the display fragment (since the position does not always equal the database key.

Answer (score 0):

For RecyclerView , use ArrayList for simplicity

And change your onBindViewHolder like this

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position){
    System.out.println(position);
    viewHolder.setData(mData.get(position));


viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = ProfPager.newIntent(getActivity(), position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

I assume mData as ArrayList